# Increasing the view by 1 each time some url hits?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here I want to increase the number of views by 1 each time the detail view is called.How can I do it ?

```
class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    package_desc = models.TextField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0) #want to increase views by 1 when detail_package url hits
```

views.py

```
class DetailPackage(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = PackageDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    queryset = Package.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
path('<slug>/detail/', DetailPackage.as_view(), name='detail_package'),
```

I am very new to django rest framework.So am I going the right way by using the generics API view for such cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the retrieve method on (generics.RetrieveAPIView)..take a look at this http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.generics/RetrieveAPIView.html#retrieve

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
from django.db.models import F


class DetailPackage(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    ...

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)

        # increment the value
        type(instance).objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(
            views=F('views') + 1,
        )

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: why we need `F` and filter?

Comment: To avoid race condition issues.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aprimus suggested I solved this by overriding the retrieve() method like this:

Please correct me if I didn't do it correctly.

```
class DetailPackage(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = PackageDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    queryset = Package.objects.all()

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.views += 1
        instance.save()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions